# how do i chnage the desktop icon for a visual basic program (.exe)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, icons

im making a vb.net app and i want to set the icon, how can i do this?

**--edit--**

turns out i was a bit confused, and it was working. but the answers can still be useful for others.

Comment: Does it show up with the correct icon in your debug/release directory?  How are you "publishing" the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question and issue, your setup/installer might be missing something.

1. It would seem you did create a shortcut, add it to the Setup project to install to the Desktop (else you wouldnt have one at all)
2. Select the shortcut in your setup project, open the properties window
3. Click `Target`.  The list of files you are installing will come up. Select the App.Exe (ie the main executable "MyApp.exe" ususally the primary output).  I think `Icon` is supposed to be set to "Icon" as well.

I think those 2 things combined link the Desktop Shortcut's Icon property to Use the App.Exe's.  If there is also a shortcut in the user's programs menu do the same thing (or drag drop a copy).

You are basically doing to the Setup Project's shortcut what you would do to a normal desktop icon to change it or set it.  The proj apparently fills in the actual path etc at install.

**EDIT**

PUBLISH simply compiles everything and produces files for the dev to distribute.  It is called PUBLISH because in many cases the output includes a ready to use Setup program for the END USER  to install on the PC.  (Based on your new Pic, you are trying to reinstall everytime you click the icon or file inside the folder.)

Again, if you do not add a Setup proj to your project, the default one is used and it gives no option for where to install and does not add a shortcut.

Just delete all that junk, Publish again to the default location (`VS Studio\...Project name\bin\Publish`).  Go to that folder and run setup.  It will still install to `Users\AppData..` but will add a shortcut (to the program) to the start menu.

For a desktop icon, do the "Send To Desktop ..." thing. To INSTALL an icon, you have to add and modify a Setup proj to your Solution.

HTH

Comment: `saved it` sounds like it got there outside a publish/setup process - ie manually.  In which case change the icon prop manually.

Comment: no, i used the publish in vs2012, and set it to publish on the desktop.

Comment: the output from PUBLISH is a directory of files ... you might be looking at an icon for that folder or one of the setups and not your actual app.  Unless you create a Setup Proj, the default setup from Publish just copies files and none of mine have ever creates a desktop icon (might be new to 2012, but doubtful), so I dont know where your Shortcut came from.

Comment: again, ts not a shortcut, its the app itself on the desktop.

Comment: thats not your app - look at the properties it points to a one click or something from Publish.  Publish is different from Setup.  Pub just makes Setup files and makes them available; setup INSTALLS on the PC.

Comment: when i click `setup` OR my "program" for the first, it opens a install, from then on it opens "verifying application requirements" and then launches the program, i may not i am not sure what i am doing, but i can tell you its not a shortcut even if it may not be the app. if you could help me "publish" or produce this properly i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

'The folder shows the icon for the app, but the icon for the form is different.  change the form's icon(in the property grid) to the same as the app and you should see it then.

When you publish it there's 2 files produced that are basically setup files.  One relies on the ClickOnce Application Deployment Support Library and the other is a standalone setup app.  Since neither one is the actual app you designed, they aren't going to have the icon you want.  You'll probably have to investigate other more configurable deployment options.

Comment: nope, the form icon is set right, it works for the top-left corner and the task-bar icon, it just doesn't work for the desktop icon.